# What specifically does a $g_d^r$ on a curve mean in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I've encountered some issues understanding exactly what's meant by a $g_d^r$ on a curve in algebraic geometry. Specifically, Hartshorne defines it as follows (just after lemma IV.5.1 on page 341):

> The symbol $g_d^r$ will stand for "a linear system of dimension $r$ and degree $d$."

When we write this symbol, do we allow for non-complete linear systems? For instance, can we say that $\Bbb P^1$ has a $g_2^1$? There definitely is a degree-two map $\Bbb P^1\to\Bbb P^1$ given by $[x:y]\mapsto [x^2:y^2]$, but there is no divisor $D$ on $\Bbb P^1$ with $\deg D=2$ and $\dim |D|=1$, since $\mathcal{O}(D)\cong\mathcal{O}(n)$ for some $n$ and $\dim H^0(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}(n))=n+1$. (Here $|D|$ is the projective space associated to the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(D)$, i.e. $\Bbb P(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(D)))$.)

The reason I ask is that later in the text there are some problems where we talk about "having a $g_3^1$" or something like that and it would be convenient to know that this means a divisor $D$ with $\deg D=3$ and $\dim |D|=1$. On the other hand, using "has a $g_3^1$" to mean "has a degree three map to $\Bbb P^1$" (even if it's not the map associated to a complete linear system) is also convenient, so I'm a little stumped which one I'm supposed to take as the definition.

Comment: Typically, it would mean complete linear systems.

Comment: @Mohan thanks, that's helpful - I managed to prove that these linear systems have to be complete in the situations I'm thinking about via Clifford's theorem.